# I would like to be able to include EJS template data into a partial view and have it render on all pages the partial is called

Tags: node.js, layout, ejs, templating

I am working on layouts and templating. I have a site where I have files "views/partials/header.ejs" and "views/partial/footer.ejs". I have the app.js file with templating set up as follows:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const date = require(__dirname + '/date.js');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));


app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  const year = date.getYear();

  res.render('home', {copyrightYear: year})
});



app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```

What I need to do is pass the const copyrightYear into the partial "footer" instead of having to to input into each route. Any advice would be welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do that because when you make a request the server get the required file the does the logic on it and then it send it back to the browser .

so when you use this

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

  const year = date.getYear();

  res.render('home', {copyrightYear: year})
});
```

the server will get the home file which includes the partials files then pass the data then send it to the browser .

so you must make separate request for each file you want and then do the logic on it